# Binomial coefficients modulo a prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, finite-fields

Consider an odd prime $p\equiv1 \pmod {16}$ and set $M=\frac{p-1}{2}$ for notational convenience. Then is there even a single prime $p$ of the above form for which the following congruence holds? $$\binom{M}{M/2}\binom{M}{M/4}\equiv \pm \binom{M}{3M/8}\binom{M}{7M/8}\pmod p ?$$

Here the symbol $\binom{n}{r}$ is a binomial coefficient and is defined as $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

I am trying to prove something significantly more abstract but have managed to reduce it down to proving that the above statement can never hold. I have written some code to check this for primes of the above form less than $1000$ and found no counter examples. My attempts to find results on binomial coefficients $\pmod p$ have mostly involved Lucas' theorem which does not seem very applicable here. I would appreciate a solution, reference or possible strategies I might try.

---

Added later: The more general problem.

Let $$f_a(x)=x(x^4-1)(x^4+ax^2+1)$$ be a family of polynomials in $
\mathbb F_p[t]$ in the parameter $a\in \overline {\mathbb F}_p$.

Let $$\sum c_{\alpha}x^\alpha := f_a(x)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} $$ and note that the $c_\alpha$ are polynomials in $a$. Now make the $4
\times 4$ matrix whose $(i,j)$th entry is $c_{pi-j}$ for $1\leq i,j \leq 4$. Then I want to show that this matrix is non-invertible for values of $a$ other than $a=2,-2$. In other words, I want to show that the determinant $d(a)$ has irreducible factors other than $(a-2)$ and $(a+2)$.

What I have managed to prove is that $d(a)$ is a polynomial of degree $\frac{3(p-1)}{2}$ and also that $(a-2)$ and $(a+2)$ occur with the same multiplicity in the factorization of $d(a)$ in $\mathbb F_p[a]$. So for a contradiction, suppose $d(a)=\alpha(a^2-4)^{\frac{3(p-1)}{4}}$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb F_p$. Then, the ratio of the leading term and the constant term must be 1. The leading term is given by the square of the right hand side in the top most equation and the constant term is given by the square of the left hand side. The other coefficients are very difficult to extract and it is lucky that I even managed to get the leading and constant terms. So I am hoping that if by some combinatorial argument I can rule out this congruence, then I will have proved that the determinant has to have an irreducible factor other than $(a-2)$ and $(a+2)$.

Comment: Do you have any clue what LHS/RHS (modulo $p$) might be equal to?

Comment: I have no clue. They seem to be completely at random.

Comment: A heuristic note: if we let $P'_n$ be the $n^{th}$ prime congruent to $1$ mod $16$ and if we chose two numbers $(a_n,b_n)$ at random mod each $P'_n$, the probability that no solution to $a_n=\pm b_n$ exists in the first $N$ terms is bounded below by $$\prod_{n=1}^{N}(1-2/P_n).$$ This product is zero in the limit, suggesting a counterexample exists unless a pattern does - but of the primes up to $10^8$, this product is still $0.619$ - so even if we checked that far on a random sequence, we would still be less likely to find a $a_n=\pm b_n$ pair than not to.

Comment: (cont.) My point being that strong computational evidence would require that one examine *way* more than the primes up to $10000$; I got Mathematica to go up to $244737$ and found nothing, but computing the binomial coefficients seems to be rather expensive (...though maybe less so if I could tell Mathematica to do this computation mod $p$, though I still don't know of any methods better than the usual formula, which uses $O(p)$ multiplication mod $p$ - which is really bad if you want a long search)

Comment: (Added for completeness of comment: I wrote some code to check up to $10^7$ - didn't find anything)

Comment: @RKD can you say the significantly more abstract thing you want to prove? that might actually help to prove the thing you asked as your question

Comment: @mathworker21 Per your request, I have added some additional information.

Comment: Just to check that I have the right determinant. When $p=17$, the determinant of that 4x4 matrix is
$$8(a+2)^8(a-2)^8(a^2-5)^4,$$ and the presence of that last factor is crucial for your purpose?

Comment: I still wonder what the original problem is? The exponent in $f_a(x)^{(p-1)/2}$ somehow suggests a character sum involving a quadratic character, but I may be off :-)

Comment: You can find a bunch of congruences of similar shape in *Binomial coefficients and Jacobi sums*, by Hudson and Williams.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it's been a while but yes the presence of that last factor is critical. For some more information, this is about superspecial hyperelliptic curves in the family $y^2 =x(x^4-1)(x^4+ax^2+1)$. I was trying to prove that for all primes $p = 1,7 \mod 8$, and $p>7$, there is a superspecial curve in this family.